# Is there an image slider that uses IMG tags instead of DIV backgrounds?

Tags: jquery, image, slider

I've added Nivo Slider to my website, but it bit me as it uses the background tag to display it's images.

But my problem with that is that I'm implementing a price list and use *external images* from sources like [IceCat](http://icecat.biz). As it now uses the images as the background of DIVs, *I have no control over the size*. This results in images that are *bigger than the slider*.

Thus I'm looking for a simple jQuery slider that uses IMG tags instead of DIV tags that allows me to fade and specify the *maximum width* of the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [slideVuewerPro](http://www.gcmingati.net/wordpress/wp-content/lab/jquery/svwt/)